# How to enable storage account backup for app service / web app using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service

```
$sa=Get-AzStorageaccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName
$con=$sa.context
#newconatiner
New-AzStorageContainer -Context $con -Name $containerName -Permission off

#Get-azstoragecontainersastoken -Name $containerName -Context $con
#get uri
$r=New-azstoragecontainersastoken -Context $con -Name $containerName -Permission rwdl -FullUri
#enable storage backup
New-AzWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webappname -StorageAccountUrl $r
Edit-azwebappbackupconfiguration -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $webappname -FrequencyInterval $FrequencyInterval -FrequencyUnit $FrequencyUnit -RetentionPeriodInDays $RetentionPeriodInDays -StorageAccountUrl $r
```

The above lines of code throws an error saying storage access is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands from the official MS document for Back up a web app using PowerShell

```
$webappname="mywebapp$(Get-Random -Minimum 100000 -Maximum 999999)"
$storagename="$($webappname)storage"
$container="appbackup"
$location="West Europe"
$backupname="backup1"

# Create a resource group.
New-AzResourceGroup -Name myResourceGroup -Location $location

# Create a storage account.
$storage = New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup `
-Name $storagename -SkuName Standard_LRS -Location $location

# Create a storage container.
New-AzStorageContainer -Name $container -Context $storage.Context

# Generates an SAS token for the storage container, valid for one month.
# NOTE: You can use the same SAS token to make backups in Web Apps until -ExpiryTime
$sasUrl = New-AzStorageContainerSASToken -Name $container -Permission rwdl `
-Context $storage.Context -ExpiryTime (Get-Date).AddMonths(1) -FullUri

# Create an App Service plan in Standard tier. Standard tier allows one backup per day.
New-AzAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name $webappname `
-Location $location -Tier Standard

# Create a web app.
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name $webappname `
-Location $location -AppServicePlan $webappname

# Create a one-time backup
New-AzWebAppBackup -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name $webappname `
-StorageAccountUrl $sasUrl -BackupName $backupname

# List statuses of all backups that are complete or currently executing.
Get-AzWebAppBackupList -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroup -Name $webappname
```

Source for above PowerShell command is : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-backup-onetime